# packages not upgraded

Tags: upgrade

To update packages, I tried command

`sudo apt update`

which responded,

`4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.`

then,

`sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

both responded,

`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.`

then,

`sudo apt list --upgradable`

which responded,

```
apt-transport-https/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2.4.8 all [upgradable from: 2.4.7]
apt-utils/jammy-updates 2.4.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.7]
apt/jammy-updates 2.4.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.7]
libapt-pkg6.0/jammy-updates 2.4.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.7]
```

how can i upgrade these 4 packages?

Comment: try `sudo apt dist-upgrade`    https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade

Comment: @sinclair thanks for this suggestion, i tried it also and edited the question but response was 
```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  apt apt-transport-https apt-utils libapt-pkg6.0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

```

Comment: uh, this usually works for me, this might help you:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it

Comment: Thanks a lot brother, I individually install all packages listed `apt list --upgradable` using command `sudo apt-get install <pkg-name>`

Comment: Please understand the reason. All the `apt` packages are currently in phased updates (which is evident from several Q&A's on this site). So either patiently wait, or disable phased updates on your system.

Comment: When confronted by apt doing something unexpected, add the use of `apt-cache policy <package_name>` to your toolbox.